# Flask request.form[] not pulling data

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to post a simple html form and pull the data into python/flask. request.form does not appear to be pulling my form data.

I have a function created to pull the variables if the request method is POST, but the URL ends up with the variables being blank. See code below

```
@app.route('/inquire',methods=['POST','GET'])
def inquire():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.form['dname']
        email = request.form['demail']
        message = request.form['dmessage']
        return 
redirect(url_for('inquire_success',name=name,email=email,message=message))


    return render_template('inquire.html')
@app.route('/inquiresuccess/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def inquire_success(name,email,message):
    return render_template('inquiresuccess.html',name=name,email=email,message=message)
```

the html below :

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="main">
        <form method="post" class="form" action="{{ 
url_for('inquire_success' }}">
        <h2>Inquire below and we'll get back to you</h2>
        <label>Name :</label>
        <input type="text" name="dname" id="dname" value="name">
        <label>Email :</label>
        <input type="text" name="demail" id="demail" value="email">
        <label>Project info :</label>
        <textarea class="messagebox" name="dmessage" id="dmessage" 
value="message">
            </textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value=Submit>
        </form>
```

I would like the code to redirect me to inquiresuccess.html with the variables displayed. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form looks to be posting to the wrong endpoint. Try changing

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="{{ url_for('inquire_success' }}">
```

to

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="{{ url_for('inquire' }}">
```